# starting point cannot be resolved into a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I'm building my very first android app. Trying to get my splash screen to work. But Splash.java is showing an error " StartingPoint cannot be resolved to a type.

Here is my manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.arjun.add"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.arjun.add.StartingPoint" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEDAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my Splash.Java

```
package com.arjun.add;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle ArjunSharma) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(ArjunSharma);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread (){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new   Intent(Splash.this, StartingPoint.class ); 
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

}
```

Hope you guys can help me out

Comment: `StartingPoint` should be the name of the class that your next activity will be. Please check your class name again. And try to `clean` and `build` the app.

Comment: What is `StartingPoint`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.arjun.add"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.arjun.add.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.arjun.add.MainActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT: note that put `MainActivity` as your starting point, that is first activity after splash screen

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest defining StartingPoint you have the category defined as android.intent.category.DEDAULT, should be android.intent.category.DEFAULT.